# agreement among more than one clustering solution

Tags: clustering

There are multiple methods to compare the agreement between two different clustering solutions (e.g. Rand index). Are there methods that compare the agreement between more than two clustering solutions?

use case: My algorithm aims to derive measurement models from measured variables. For example my true measurement models are variable A,B,D measures latent variable L1; variable C,E,F measures latent variable L2. My algorithm is unstable at smaller sample sizes, which means when it runs on different small samples, the algorithm uncovers different measurement models. sometimes discovers A,B but not together with D as measuring the same latent, sometime discovers B, D but together with A as measuring the same latent). I wish to test the stability of the solution. One way of top of my head is that I could count number of times a pair of variable occurs in the same cluster. If I only have two runs, I could use rand index to measure agreement. but in this case I need to have multiple runs.

Comment: How are you thinking about agreement in this context? Eg, are you asking if the algorithm settles on the same number of clusters each time, or if the same patterns are grouped together, something else? Moreover, what is the clustering algorithm you're using, & what distance measure? (That tells us what you think about the nature of the clusters to be found.) What method would you use if you had just 2 solutions, the Rand index? Note that a measure of cluster quality is at least theoretically distinct from the agreement of that measure on multiple solutions.

Comment: You can compute the similarity (Rand or what you prefer) within pairs of solutions and than perform hierarchical clustering (say, complete linkage) of the solutions.

Comment: @gung I am clustering variables rather than observations here. More specifically, I am trying to derive measurement models from measured variable. and I would like to evaluate how often are the same observed variables  measures the same latent variable. I would use Rand index if there is only two solution...

Comment: You seem to have lost part of your response. Also, can you edit this information into your question?

Comment: @gung I have edited questions. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with using the average Rand index?

Rand index is the accuracy of pairs, and an average accuracy is quite common measure.

Comment: I think this might work. I am waiting to see if there are other answers. Can you give a citation for average rand index? Thanks!

Comment: Using the average is not something one could publish.